# Angular material autocomplete z-index issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an autocomplete feature but I can't display the results as I want, I think it's a z-index issue, but I couldn't solve it.

I can use `md-autocomplete`, it doesn't have this problem, but I want to learn what's causing this.

As soon as I start typing, my input goes up and results are displayed below in the navigation bar.

I changed `$http` to an array to mock the results.

Here's my code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    #testing > div > div > div > md-input-container {
      margin:0;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>

  <md-content>
    <md-toolbar id="testing">
      <div layout-wrap layout="row">
        <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl" class="md-toolbar-tools">
          <div flex="40" layout-align="center">
            <md-input-container class="" flex="" layout="row">
              <label class="search-color">Search</label>
              <input ng-model="searchInput" class="text1" type="text">

            </md-input-container>
            <md-item-template flex="100" layout="column">
              <div ng-repeat="a in details">
                <div>{{a}}</div>
              </div>
            </md-item-template>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
  </md-content>

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    angular.module('BlankApp').controller('SearchCtrl', ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {

    //$scope.searchInput = "";
    $scope.$watch('searchInput', function() {
      if ($scope.searchInput) {
        fetch();
      }
    });

    function fetch() {
      var arr = ["result1", "result2", "result3", "result4"];
      $scope.details = arr;
    }
  }]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's my plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/LQ1HxV6vmPkUGYHnVfCg?p=preview